# Eclipse immediately undeletes deleted file

Tags: eclipse, git, file, log4j

When attempting to delete log4j.properties Eclipse undeletes in the very next moment. The file is not used at the moment, no build process is running, the project containing the file is not being deployed. Yet the file is being restored immediately. Even when the IDE and all shell (ie. Git bash) sessions are closed and the file is not open anywhere, it can be successfully deleted using Windows Explorer or Total Commander, but the moment the IDE is started the file is there again.

The intention was to replace the old properties structure with an xml, but I couldn't even overwrite it as upon saving the original content got restored. Any advice on this?

Comment: At which location did you delete `log4j.properties`?  Which project builders and natures have the project you are talking about (see the `.project` file)?

Comment: The file was located under src/main/resources. Builders: org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder, o.e.wst.common.common.project.facet.core.builder, o.e.wst.validation.validationbuilder and org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder. Natures: org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature, o.e.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature, o.e.jdt.core.javanature, o.e.m2e.core.maven2Nature, o.e.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature and o.e.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature.

Comment: Is the project under version control?

Comment: It was. I untracked the file and moved to another folder, from where I was able to delete without being undeleted by the IDE. Strange.